# Need to get out of a foreach and a while loop

Tags: c#, foreach, while-loop

I have this foreach loop in a book method.

```
foreach (var loop in _db.Owners)
{
    while (loop.ITEM== submittedITEM && loop.ITEM != null)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

problem is, if it's never false, it never breaks out of the foreach, it just keeps going and going and going.  I tried to add a return true, but then it doesn't loop through all of objects like they need to! How do I get it to run through the list of owners, and if none of them return false, it returns true?

Comment: infinite loop... why not use an if statement?

Comment: use a for loop and an if statement

Comment: You're misunderstanding the `while` loop's behavior.  Step through it on a piece of paper or whiteboard:  The `loop` variable gets set to the first element of `_db.Owners`, then the while loop starts.  Note that nothing in the while loop ever changes `loop` so if it is not already matching the while loop condition, it will run forever

Comment: What type is `_db.Owners`?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the while with an if, and add `return true` after the foreach loop.

```
foreach (var loop in _db.Owners)
{
    if (loop.ITEM== submittedITEM && loop.ITEM != null)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Comment: nope, still keeps going and going.  _db.Owner has a count of 15 and it goes way past that.

Comment: Sounds like there's some issue with _db.Owner, then.  The expected behavior of a foreach loop on a 15-element collection is 15 iterations.

Comment: @BlowFish The only way a foreach loop would continue to iterate for a finite collection is if it defined a `GetEnumerator` method that returns an infinite enumerator.  We need to know more about what `_db.Owners` is.

Comment: Did you use the code exactly as Antony has it in his answer? There is no reason it should loop infinitely given what his example has.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is so different, but I narrowed my count to potentialItems and then ran a foreach and if through that. Thanks everyone!

```
 foreach (var trialItem in potentialItemss)
                            {
                                if (submittedITEM.Equals(trialItem)) return false;
                            }
```